# How to create pull request for my changes but exclude others' from remote branch to master?

Tags: git

I have forked a repo and made changes for a specific issue on top of remote branch named "dev".  I need to push my changes to master branch of remote. However other people made changes in upstream dev.
Such as

> ```
> RepoA |-----> master
>          |-----> dev
>             |------> change A
>             |------> change B
>             |------> change X
>             |------> change Y
> ```

Now, how do I cherry pick my changes alone (change A and B) in upstream dev and push it to upstream master? TIA!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to relocate two commits {A,B} from a local branch `dev` to `upstream/master`.

Simply checkout master, pull any changes, and cherry-pick the commits you want.

```sh
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git log -n3 dev
git cherry-pick [B_sha] [A_sha]
# git push origin master
```

You could also simply rebase `dev` against `origin/master`, but I am assuming they have diverged dramatically at some point.

Comment: Actually I want to push from upstream/dev to upstream/master. In my organization, its not allowed to fork directly from master.